# Why didn't Draco Malfoy buy a Firebolt?

Tags: harry-potter, quidditch, flying-brooms

After Harry was gifted a Firebolt by his godfather Sirius Black, why didn't Draco Malfoy buy a Firebolt, seeing as he bought a Nimbus 2001 after seeing Harry with his Nimbus 2000.

Comment: to my understanding in the books, firebolts were currently limited to just major world teams, minus the 1 used for publicity with an "open bid".

Comment: Nah it was price on request and they were limited edition, but there's nothing to suggest they were exclusively for international teams, I mean, they were stocked by a non-specialist, high street Quidditch shop. It was just that the Irish side (among others, presumably) did buy them, which is obviously a good thing to mention when trying to sell them :P

Comment: @Himarm Fire bolt is never limited, it is said that after a year of its release it crossed the sales of nimbus 2000 and 2001 Source: Harrypotter.wikia.com

Comment: Just because Harry is using it , Draco always wanted to be different from Harry.It's just like Harry would never buy the Nimbus 2001 ..

Comment: I got the impression that they were buying the newest model each time, a bit like having the latest technology.

Comment: After buying seven brand new brooms and getting no Quidditch cup for it, I doubt that Lucius was at all keen about buying an even more wildly expensive one.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Well, I think you've answered your own question, really, if you don't mind my saying so. He bought a Nimbus 200**1** after seeing Harry's Nimbus 200**0**.

He doesn't want the same broom as Harry, certainly, he has to one-up him, doesn't he? Remember when McGonagall confiscated Harry's Firebolt, and Wood tried to get it back, but failed? Harry and Wood has this conversation:

> 'I reckon it's time you ordered a new broom, Harry. There's an order form at the back of *Which Broomstick* ... you could get a Nimbus Two Thousand and One, like Malfoy's got.'
>
> 'I'm not buying anything Malfoy thinks is good,' said Harry flatly.
>
> *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban* - p.181 - Bloomsbury - chapter 12, *The Patronus*

I'd say Malfoy's mind would work more or less the same way, don't you think? He isn't buying any broomstick *Harry Potter* thinks is good.

Of course, I'm sure he'd have *liked* a comparable broomstick of his own, if he could've had one. But a Firebolt is an international-standard broomstick. And I'm not sure even Lucius Malfoy is going to shell out for another (this time, even more preposterously expensive) broomstick for his son, just one year later. Think back to *The Chamber of Secrets*:

> Malfoy, who had reached for the glass eye, said, 'I thought you were going to buy me a present.'
>
> 'I said I would buy you a racing broom,' said his father, drumming his fingers on the counter.
>
> 'What's the good of that if I'm not in the house team?' said Malfoy, looking sulky and bad-tempered. 'Harry Potter got a Nimbus Two Thousand last year. Special permission from Dumbledore so he could play for Gryffindor. He's not even that good, it's just because he's *famous* ... famous for having a stupid *scar* on his forehead ...'
>
> Malfoy bent down to examine a shelf full of skulls.
>
> '... everyone thinks he's so *smart*, wonderful *Potter* with his *scar* and his *broomstick* -'
>
> 'You have told me this at least a dozen times already,' said Mr Malfoy, with a quelling look at his son ...
>
> *Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets* - pp.42-3 - Bloomsbury - chapter 4, *At Flourish and Blotts*

I'd say Lucius Malfoy is getting a bit tired of all this, wouldn't you?

And then again:

> 'I hope my son will amount to more than a thief or a plunderer, Borgin,' said Mr Malfoy coldly and Mr Borgin said quickly, 'No offence, sir, no offence meant -'
>
> 'Though if his school marks don't pick up,' said Mr Malfoy, more coldly still, 'that may indeed be all he is fit for.'
>
> *Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets* - p.44 - Bloomsbury - chapter 4, *At Flourish and Blotts*

I don't think he's going to be bought another brand new broomstick, especially not an international-standard one.

And, anyway, don't you think it's admitting defeat a bit? Harry Potter gets a Nimbus Two Thousand, Malfoy gets the entire Slytherin team Nimbus Two Thousand and Ones and then, one year later, he has to buy himself another new stick, because his suddenly isn't big enough anymore.

Comment: Wow, Lucius has no chill.